# Проблема с SDL в C++

Tags: c++, sdl

Изучаю SDL, и сейчас встретился с проблемой. 
Использую пример кода с сайта:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL initialization failed. SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "SDL initialization succeeded!";
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

В свойствах проекта всё установлено правильно, все нужные библиотеки установлены. SDL2.dll находится в одной папке с exe-шником, но при запуске появляется данная ошибка:

> "Project3.exe" (Win32). Загружено "D:\C++
>   Projects\Project3\Debug\Project3.exe". Символы загружены.
>
> "Project3.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll".
>
> "Project3.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll".
>
> "Project3.exe" (Win32). Загружено
>   "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll".
>
> "Project3.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Program Files\AVAST
>   Software\Avast\x86\aswhook.dll".
>
> Поток 0x3a0 завершился с кодом -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
>
> Программа "[8024] Project3.exe" завершилась с кодом -1073741701
>   (0xc000007b).

В чем проблема?

Скрины настроек проекта: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нехватает какой-то библиотеки

Comment: Переходи на Linux, там намного легче устроенна система компиляции!

Comment: попробуйте #include "SDL.h"`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan К сожалению не сработало(

Comment: @AlexF dll вроде.

Comment: @RedBull Можете посоветовать с чего начать изучения Линукса, что лучше всего ставить?

Comment: @Redis поддержу предложение по изучению линукса, но сдесь важна не система, а инструмент. Изучите систему сборки, чтобы в дальнейшем у вас подобных вопросов никогда не возникало. На сегодняшний день стандартом в области систем сборки, по-факту, является cmake. Также есть и другие вроде autotools, но они не столь популярные и распространенные (главным образом либо из-за привязки к IDE, либо из-за высокой сложности, а иногда и того и другого). Так, например, исходя из вопроса вообще не понятно что за систему вы используете

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Использовал Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: @Redis и? Та же вижла, например, поддерживает cmake. Вы, как я понимаю, используете то о чем я и писал выше: IDE зависимый и сложный инструмент

Comment: ну что это такое? код то собирается, зачем человеку предлагать другую систему сборки. Не понимаю. А проблема скорее всего в том, что сам код собрался как 32битный, а sdl*dll - 64битная.

Comment: @KoVadim ну а как бы это произошло используй он нормальную систему сборки? В cmake такого просто не может произойти

Comment: cmake - нормальная система сборки? мда... Но даже она никак бы не помогла с его проблемой. Ну совсем никак.

Comment: @KoVadim "cmake - нормальная система сборки? мда..." - может поделитесь тогда хорошей системой сборки по вашему мнению? "Но даже она никак бы не помогла с его проблемой. Ну совсем никак." - вы, видимо, с ней совершенно незнакомы...

Comment: cmake - это генератор, сам cmake не умеет собирать. Поэтому он не система сборки. А с проблемой не помог, так как теперь у вопрошающего две проблемы - его, которая никак не исправилась, и ещё настройка/установка/написания скрипта cmake. Если бы в ответе показали готовый cmake скрипт... И да, я cmake к сожалению хорошо знаком.

Comment: @KoVadim чего-чего? "cmake - это генератор, сам cmake не умеет собирать" - у вас уж слишком узкое понимание понятия `система сборки` - под такое можно разве что `make` натянуть. Но все же, так какая система сборки, по-вашему, хорошая?

Comment: есть ещё ninja, msbuild. sharpmake и другие. для меня хорошая система сборки должна быть относительно простой и генерировать минимум дополнительного хлама (вот тут мне cmake и не нравится сильно). Если бы он генерировал один make файл, у меня не было к нему вопросов.

Comment: @KoVadim не могу не заметить, что вы уклонились от вопроса

Comment: я ответил на вопрос. К сожалению, я не буду продолжать эту дискуссию. я думаю, я полностью раскрыл вопрос, объяснил, почему мне не нравиться cmake и как это можно было  бы исправить. Также я уточнил, почему считаю Ваш комментарий, что cmake помог бы человеку немного странным.

Comment: @KoVadim погодите, так это msbuild вы считаете хорошей программой сборки?... и sharpmake... если это, по-вашему, хорошие системы, то мы с вами из абсолютно разных миров. И я это даже не о том, что вы из мира чисто Windows-VisualStudio, а о критериях, по которых хорошее отделяется от плохого. Вы абсолютно не считаетесь ни с кросплатформенностью, ни с простотой, ни с лаконичностью, а, насколько я понмаю, только с тем, как это работает в VisualStudio (теперь мне стало понятно, почему вы жаловались на то что cmake много чего генерит - просто все нагенеренное вам в дерево проекта попадает)

Comment: я не сказал, что msbuild хорошая система сборки. (при этом то, что я написал ninja, Вы конечно не увидели). И более того, пишете человеку, у которого дома три машины на генте и одна на убунте... да...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я просто посмотрел первое попавшееся видио на Ютубе. Всё дело действительно оказалось в файле SDL2.dll. Вероятнее всего я скопировал файл для 64 битной разрядности, и по этому программа не работала. Если что то вот то видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sfn7yOiwJLw